# custom annotation apple mapkit

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, apple-maps

I am trying to assign two custom annotations, one called "arsenal.png" and one called "chelsea.png"

Using apple mapkit framework, xcode 7.

Need assistance with code to achieve the customized markers.

here is my implementation file:

```
// TrucksViewController.m

#import "TrucksViewController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"

@interface TrucksViewController ()

@end

//Wimbledon Coordinates
#define WIMB_LATITUDE 51.434783;
#define WIMB_LONGITUDE -0.213428;

//Stadium Coordinates
#define ARSENAL_LATITUDE 51.556899;
#define ARSENAL_LONGITUDE -0.106483;

#define CHELSEA_LATITUDE 51.481314;
#define CHELSEA_LONGITUDE -0.190129;

//Span
#define THE_SPAN 0.20f;

@implementation TrucksViewController
@synthesize myMapView;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialisation

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {

    self.title = @"Trucks";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO     withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIViewController Delegates

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Update support iOS 7
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

// Revert to default settings
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Create Region
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

//Center
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude = ARSENAL_LATITUDE;
center.longitude = ARSENAL_LONGITUDE;

//Span
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

//Region
myRegion.center = center;
myRegion.span = span;

//Set our mapview
[myMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

//Annotation
NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
Annotation * myAnn;

//Arsenal annotation
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = ARSENAL_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = ARSENAL_LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Arsenal FC";
myAnn.subtitle = @"The Gunners";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

//Chelsea annotation
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = CHELSEA_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = CHELSEA_LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Chelsea FC";
myAnn.subtitle = @"The Blue Lions";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

[self.myMapView addAnnotations:locations];

}

@end
```

***Additions posted 12/11/2013 18:31 hours Eastern***

Updated Annotations.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * title;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * subtitle;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * imageName;

@end
```

Updated Annotations.m file

```
#import "Annotation.h"

@implementation Annotation
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle, imageName;

@end
```

Updated TrucksViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface TrucksViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;

@end
```

Updated TrucksViewController.m

(snip of code)

```
//Arsenal annotation
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = ARSENAL_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = ARSENAL_LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Arsenal FC";
myAnn.subtitle = @"The Gunners";
myAnn.imageName = @"arsenal";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

//Chelsea annotation
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = CHELSEA_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = CHELSEA_LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Chelsea FC";
myAnn.subtitle = @"The Blue Lions";
myAnn.imageName = @"chelsea";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

[self.myMapView addAnnotations:locations];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here is my updated TrucksViewController.m file:
***12/11/2013 at 20:07 Eastern***

```
// TrucksViewController.m

#import "TrucksViewController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"

@interface TrucksViewController ()


@end

//Wimbledon Coordinates
#define WIMB_LATITUDE 51.434783;
#define WIMB_LONGITUDE -0.213428;

//Stadium Coordinates
#define ARSENAL_LATITUDE 51.556899;
#define ARSENAL_LONGITUDE -0.106483;

#define CHELSEA_LATITUDE 51.481314;
#define CHELSEA_LONGITUDE -0.190129;

//Span
#define THE_SPAN 0.20f;

@implementation TrucksViewController
@synthesize myMapView;

//insert code per Anna

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:    (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"ann";
    MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (av == nil)
    {
        av = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation     reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
    }
    else
    {
        av.annotation = annotation;
    }

    Annotation *ann = (Annotation *)annotation;
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ann.imageName];

    return av;
}

//return nil (default view) if annotation is not our custom type
return nil;
}

//end new code per Anna

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialisation

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    // Set the title for this view controller
    // Note: In future we will copy over the title from any created     UINavigationBar objects
    self.title = @"Trucks";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO         withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIViewController Delegates

- (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Update support iOS 7
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

// Revert to default settings
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Create Region
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

//Center
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude = ARSENAL_LATITUDE;
center.longitude = ARSENAL_LONGITUDE;

//Span
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

//Region
myRegion.center = center;
myRegion.span = span;

//Set our mapview
[myMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

//Annotation
NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
Annotation * myAnn;

//Arsenal annotation
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = ARSENAL_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = ARSENAL_LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Arsenal FC";
myAnn.subtitle = @"The Gunners";
myAnn.imageName = @"arsenal.png";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

//Chelsea annotation
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = CHELSEA_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = CHELSEA_LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Chelsea FC";
myAnn.subtitle = @"The Blue Lions";
myAnn.imageName = @"chelsea.png";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

[self.myMapView addAnnotations:locations];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to implement the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method to show images for your annotations instead of the standard red pin.

In that delegate method, you need to create and return an `MKAnnotationView` with its `image` property set to the image you want for the annotation.

You will get a reference to the annotation the map view is asking for a view for and using the annotation's properties, you set the image accordingly.

You *could* base it on the annotation's `title` value but I'd suggest the following approach instead:

1. Add a `imageName` property of type `NSString` to your `Annotation` class.  Set this property to the image name to use for the annotation before you call `addAnnotation` on it.  For example:

   ```
   myAnn.title = @"Arsenal FC";
   myAnn.subtitle = @"The Gunners";
   myAnn.imageName = @"arsenal";
   [locations addObject:myAnn];
   ```
2. In the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, check if the annotation is of type `Annotation` and then use its `imageName` property to set the annotation view's `image` property:

   ```
   -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
   {
       if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
       {
           static NSString *reuseId = @"ann";
           MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
           if (av == nil)
           {
               av = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
           }
           else
           {
               av.annotation = annotation;
           }

           Annotation *ann = (Annotation *)annotation;
           av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ann.imageName];

           return av;
       }

       //return nil (default view) if annotation is not our custom type
       return nil;
   }
   ```

Also, don't forget to set the map view's `delegate` property otherwise the delegate method won't get called.  In Interface Builder, connect the `delegate` outlet to the view controller.

Comment: I have incorporated Step 1 above in TrucksViewController.m and updated Annotation.m and .h to include reference to imageName. Unsure on how to implement Step 2.

Comment: For step 2, add the viewForAnnotation method as given in the answer to the TrucksViewController.m file.  Make sure the map view's delegate property is set (or outlet is connected).  And of course make sure the image files arsenal.png, chelsea.png, etc are included in your project.

Comment: I have included amended TrucksViewController.m in original post above. TrucksViewController.h has an outlet, and the images are in the project. I am showing no errors (yeah!), but in Simulator/Run the points show up, but with default Red pins (not custom images).

Comment: In Interface Builder, right-click on the map view.  Connect the delegate outlet to the view controller.  Or, in viewDidLoad, add this line after the "super viewDidLoad" line: `self.myMapView.delegate = self;`

Comment: Successfully runs(!). Error free, but with this one (yellow) alert/warning:  `Assigning to 'id<MKMapViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'TrucksViewController *const __strong'`

Comment: In TrucksViewController.h, tell the compiler that the vc implements the protocol: `@interface TrucksViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {`

Comment: No issues or errors reporting. Upon running though, when single clicking the custom icon, neither the title nor subtitle is displayed (as it was with the default Red pin)

Comment: In viewForAnnotation, right after the initWithAnnotation line, put this: `av.canShowCallout = YES;`.

Comment: All issues addressed. Very much appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *viewForAnnotation* delegate method for creating custom annotation.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation
```

See the below tutorials

http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/advanced-mapkit-tutorial-for-ios-custom-callout/

http://ios-funda.blogspot.in/2012/08/custom-annotations-example.html

**EDIT**

You need to set the delegate in **viewDidLoad**

```
self.myMapView.delegate = self
```

Now in **.h**

```
@interface TrucksViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
```

Then implement the delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation  {

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *defaultPinId = @"Pin";
    CustomAnnotation *pinView = (CustomAnnotation *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinId];


    if (pinView == nil) {

        pinView = [[CustomAnnotation alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinId];
        //pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        //pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        //NSLog(@"%f",[annotation coordinate].latitude);

    }
    else    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }


    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(275, 27, 30, 30);

    //Adding a navigation inside a callout view
    btn.tag = [sid intValue];
    //NSLog(@"%i",btn.tag);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(YOUR_SELECTOR) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn;

    return pinView;

}
```

in **CustomAnnotation.m** add the below methods

```
-(id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier    {

    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self != nil) {
        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(46.0, 49.0);
        self.frame = frame;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-5, -5);
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"locatorico"] drawInRect:rect];

}
```

Comment: My apologies. I have spent several days looking through tutorials, videos, blogs, etc. (Head swimming). Not sure how to implement the suggested code above. Where do I insert the code above, and how do I associate a distinct (different) .png with each location? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using drawRect to display the image?  Why not just set the annotation view's `image` property?  You don't really need a custom annotation view class to show images for annotations.

Comment: @Anna you can simply use annotation view's image property. but if there is a complex customization needed or any additional functionalities need to be added, then this custom annotation view class will be more helpful

Comment: Although such customizations may have been needed in your case, I think they needlessly complicate and confuse the simplicity of the OP's question.

Comment: @Anna yeah may be. but this practice is always good in my opinion